# Justify angled axis text on "top" axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(tidyverse)
sales <- 
  tibble(store = rep(c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI"), each = 2),
         metric = factor(rep(c("sales", "satisfaction"), 3),
                         # levels = c("sales", "satisfaction")),
                         levels = c("satisfaction", "sales")),
         risk = factor(c("medium", "low", "low", "low", "high", "medium"),
                       levels = c("low", "medium", "high")),
         value = signif(runif(6, 0, 100), 4))

ggplot(sales, aes(store, metric)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = risk), color = "grey50") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("green", "yellow", "red")) +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top") +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1),
        legend.position = "none") +
  geom_text(aes(label = value))
```

The bottom of the x-axis text letters (eg "ABC", "DEF", etc) line up with the tick marks on the x-axis. I want to nudge this text to the right to center the text with the tick marks on the x-axis.

I can't come up with any combinations of `hjust` and `vjust` (from 0 thru 1) that will move this x-axis text horizontally. Is this possible with ggplot to justify text if it is also angled?

[image]

Comment: FYI: `vjust` and `hjust` can be negative and with absolute values of greater than one.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the tip. It seems no matter what values I use for `vjust` the text just won't move horizontally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This issue has been reported on github (https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1878). Briefly, as you move the x axis to the top, the `vjust` will work only if you apply it to `axis.text.x.top`.

So for your code, you need to do:

```r
ggplot(sales, aes(store, metric)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = risk), color = "grey50") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("green", "yellow", "red")) +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top") +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
        axis.text.x.top = element_text(vjust = 0.5),
        legend.position = "none") +
  geom_text(aes(label = value))
```

[image]